# Printing of Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$transactions = array (
array( 'SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),

array( 'SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Redemption'),

array( 'SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '1500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),

array( 'SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '200.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Reload' ),

array( 'SiteID' => 150, 'Amount' => '100.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),

array( 'SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Redemption' ),

array( 'SiteID' => 150, 'Amount' => '200.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Redemption' ),

array( 'SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),

array( 'SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '200.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),

array( 'SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '200.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Reload' ),

array( 'SiteID' =>147, 'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Redemption' )
);

$totals = null;

foreach ($transactions as $t){

$amount = (float) $t['Amount'];

if (isset($totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ])){
    $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] += (float) $amount;
} else {
    $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] = (float) $amount;
}
}

print_r ($totals);
```

Here's the code but it print's like this:

```
Array ( [147] => Array ( [D] => 455500 [W] => 460216.4 [R] => 158000 ) 

[145] => Array ( [D] => 85500 [W] => 78763.75 [R] => 14500 )

[146] => Array ( [D] => 64200 [W] => 91121.94 [R] => 42800 )
```

I need to print_r the result like this:

```
Array ( [147] => Array ( [Deposit] => 455500 [Redemption] => 460216.4 [Reload] => 158000 ) 

[145] => Array ( [Deposit] => 85500 [Redemption] => 78763.75 [Reload] => 14500 )

[146] => Array ( [Deposit] => 64200 [Redemption] => 91121.94 [Reload] => 42800 )
```

**R - Reload, W - Redemption and D - Deposit.**

Thanks and Please Response.

Comment: thanks diEcho, can you help me with my problem? Thanks :)

Comment: i cant find the changes in your desired array and currently getting array. except `D W R`, but later you write the abbreviation of D W R

Comment: Whats difference between two arrays? What you exactly want?

Comment: I just need to print the Result as D - "Deposit" and not the letter "D", R - "Reload" and "W" - Redemption. Pls help

Comment: Hi Sabin, the keys should be a word "Deposit" for ['D'] , "Reload" for ['R'] and "Redemption" for ['W"]

Comment: The value printed by you for deposit,redemption and reload is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$result=array();
foreach($total as $key=>$value)
{
    $result=array_merge($result,array($key=>array("Deposit"=>$value['D'],"Redemption"=>$value['W'],"Reload"=>$value['R'])));
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: hi, but i need to insert the SiteID at the key? how can I do that?

Comment: you have save sited as key in $total,so in my code,$key is equal to your siteid

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
foreach ($transactions as $k=>$t){

$amount = (float) $t['Amount'];

if (isset($totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ])){
    $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] += (float) $amount;
} else {
    $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] = (float) $amount;
}
}
```

Comment: just changed only in `foreach`