# Printing of Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing of Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896137/printing-of-array)

```
public function computeGHComponents()
{
    error_reporting (E_ALL^ E_NOTICE);          

    $total = null;

    $result=array();


    foreach ($this->transaction as $t){
        $amount = (float) $t['Amount'];

        if (isset($this->totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ])){
           $this->totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] += (float) $amount;
        } else {
           $this->totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] = (float) $amount;
        }
    }

    foreach($this->totals as $key => $value)
    {
        $result =            array_merge($result,array($key=>array("Deposit"=>$value['D'],"Redemption"=>$value['W'],"Reload"=>$value['R']))); 
    }

    print_r($result);   

}
```

The key should be the SiteID, how can I do that?

I need this kind of output:

```
array ([147]=>array([Deposit] => "total amount", [Reload]=> "total amount" [Redemption]=> "total amount"))

array ([150]=>array([Deposit] => "total amount", [Reload]=> "total amount" [Redemption]=> "total amount"))

array ([3]=> array([Deposit] => "total amount", [Reload]=> "total amount" [Redemption]=> "total amount"))
```

the key should be the SiteID. Please revised the code :(

Comment: Many of StackOverflow's users, like me, live in North America, where it is 2-5am depending on the time zone. Expecting an answer within 10 minutes is a bit presumptuous.

Comment: thanks sir it's a big help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal because you are using array_merge(), take a look at the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

So your SiteID which is the key will be renumbered.

Then, to keep your keys, it will be better to do this :

```
$result[$key] = array("Deposit"=>$value['D'], "Redemption"=>$value['W'], "Reload"=>$value['R']);
```

Comment: yehey! I'm finally done! :) WarfarA, it's a big help.It works! Thank you so much and more power :)